# Show Automatic Strong password iOS in Flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter, autofill

For a small coding project I manually installed my homemade Flutter app on my iPhone. This app has a Registration page, where a user can fill in their email and password to sign up for the app. To enable iOS Automatic Strong Password I used the Flutter AutofillGroup widget, and provided the appropriate AutofillHints to the corresponding textfields:

```
return AuthScaffoldView(
      title: 'Sign in',
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: AutofillGroup(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              CupertinoTextField(
                onEditingComplete: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
                placeholder: 'Email',
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                controller: model.editableUser.email,
                autofillHints: [AutofillHints.email],
                clearButtonMode: OverlayVisibilityMode.editing,
              ),
              CupertinoTextField(
                onEditingComplete: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
                placeholder: 'Wachtwoord',
                controller: model.editableUser.password,
                autofillHints: [AutofillHints.newPassword],
                clearButtonMode: OverlayVisibilityMode.editing,
              ),
              CupertinoTextField(...
```

When I run the app on my phone, the AutofillHints work as expected for the `email` TextField, but on tapping the password TextField I get the following error as Xcode output:

`[AutoFill] Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID: {bundleID} due to error: Cannot identify the calling app's process. Check teamID and bundleID in your app's application-identifier entitlement`.

I signed my app in Xcode (under `Signing & Capabilities`) with the appropriate `Team` and `Bundle Identifier`. Does anybody know where this error is coming from?

Comment: having same issues.  did you resolve this?

Comment: How was this solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by meeting the following prerequisites for Autofill Strong Password to work on iOS:

1. Set up `Associated Domains`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains. It involves serving an `apple-app-site-association` file from the root (or .well-known) directory of your webserver, and adding the `Associated Domains` entitlement to your list of app entitlements.
2. Add the `Autofill Credential Provider` entitlement to your app.

PS. The latest Flutter 2.8.x contains a bug, which is discussed here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94043, so if you want to get it working you need to either downgrade to v.2.5.x or wait for the bug fix.

EDIT: With Flutter 2.10.1 the abovementioned bug is fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to indicate to the user, whether a password is strong enough or not?
Please use this package here to do this:

https://pub.dev/packages/password_strength

Make sure to replace the password field, with this package's widget

Comment: No, I’m trying to let Apple Autofill fill in a strong password for the user, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill